# Is it ok to have incode configuration?

Tags: configuration, code-structure

We have some configuration-store classes like this:

```
public class Configuration {

    private static final Map<DocType, Map<ReportType, Template>> templates = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        Map<ReportType, Template> docZeroTemplates = new HashMap<>();
        docZeroTemplates.put(REPORT_ZERO, new Template("/templates/ReportZero.jrxml", ReportZeroSource.class));
        docZeroTemplates.put(REPORT_ONE, new Template("/templates/ReportOne.jrxml", ReportOneSource.class));
        templates.put(DocType.DOC_ZERO, docZeroTemplates);
    }

}
```

Advantages:

- Refactoring and navigation support provided by IDE.

Disadvantages:

- I'm not sure, it looks like something wrong.

I'm not even sure, that it should be called configuration.
Should I replace such classes by XML? Like this:

```
<configuration>
  <document type="document0">
    <reports>
      <report type="report0">
        <path>/templates/document0/report0.jrxml</path>
        <source>org.company.report.ReportZero</source>
      </report>
    </reports>
  </document>
</configuration>
```